# Not able to checkout elements in stream in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I am not able to checkout any element in Dev stream in Clearcase from any user except the admin user. I am getting below error :
No permission to perform operation "checkout".
Must be one of: member of object group, object owner, VOB owner, member of admin group.

I added the user group to the Primary group of clearcase in Windows, but I am still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a regular ClearCase (not CCRC with automatic or web view), type in your view:

```
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

Check if if the primary group is correct.
If not, take note of the global path (which should be like an network UNC path `\\<aServer>\path\to\view\storage`.

If not, in a regular CMD session:

```sh
set CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP=<aGroup>
doskey fp=c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe -force -chgrp "<aGroup>" -chown <aLogin> $*
fp -rec -chmod 775 \\UNC\Path\to\view.vws
fp -root \\UNC\Path\to\view.vws
```

- Replace `\\UNC\Path\to\view.vws` by the global path you have seen in the first step (the `lsview` one), as mentioned above.
- Replace `<aGroup>` by the primary group name, and `<aLogin>` by your Windows login.
  Make sure your user is part of that group.